# Dynamically Change X-axis label name in HighCharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

In my recent application I have used HighCharts , this is very nice using high chart jquery plugin and everything is doing nice . now my one problem is that , I have small space in right side of the high chart container , so in x-axis I have shown only 4 city names , but I want to actually show 8 cities names , look at the below Image, where you can see only 4 city names are mentioned , what I want to suppose the site is loaded first time in browser and after 2-3 mins the chart should automatically refresh with new cities names and their datas,
For example , now when the site is loaded it is showing delhi, mumbai, kolkata, chennai and their related data(data may be population of the city) after 2-3 mins later the chart should be refresh with new cities names like pune, bangalore, gurgaon,hydrabad and their datas respectively . Pl one thing we need to remember we only want to reload / refresh data but don't want to reload the whole website .

Any suggestions are welcome
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you post your chart code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to thank everyone who have give their best suggestion and also including demo app. I have solved my Issue something like this ,

Here  is the simple HTML code , where the chart will be load

```
 <div style="margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 0px;" id="dashboardChartcontent">
        @*Here is the chart Element*@
    </div>
```

Now below this I have called the Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
autograph();
</script>
```

At the top of the page I have declared the function using SetInterval function , look the code below:

```
 function autograph() {
    setInterval(displaygraphsecondtime, 8000);
    setInterval(displaygraphthirdtime, 6000);
    setInterval(displaygraphfirsttime, 2000);
};
```

These functions displaygraphsecondtime, displaygraphthirdtime, displaygraphfirstime are containing the code of high-chart .

Answer (score 2):

Debal,

There are built in methods provided in api. like

```
setCategories()
```

this one will help you to add new categories to the data.

here is a working  example http://jsfiddle.net/sMNr3/.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello strikers, Thanks a lot for your answer but you have put one button and on it's click event u r loading x-labels categories but I want to refresh the whole chart with new data after 1-2 mins(interval) and the previous x-label category name like delhi,kolkata will be replaced by new name and new values.

Comment: I hope you understand my problem , If you reply will be better, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `JSON`. Return it on your `PHP` or `aspx` page without any `html` code. Call this `PHP` or `aspx` page using `Ajax` in the `javascript`. And in `setInterval()` along with `addPoint` function call this `Ajax` every 2-3 minutes or any duration you want. It will update the data on the X as well as Y both the axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval() function and [addPoint function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint)

Answer (score 0):

You can use X axis categories option for dynamically updating X axis values.

```
Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({categories:arrayname}, true);
```